# Compare two directories for a certain extension and then move the missing ones to a new directory

Tags: files, directory

**Editing and changing the verbiage to make it more clear -**
I have .dm4 files in both dirA and dirB. My reference folder is dirA and I want to list all the .dm4 files which are missing in dirA which are there in dirB and then post all missing .dm4s and along with the existing .dm4s of dir A, into directory C, thus making sure that I do not miss out on any .dm4s which might exist in my dirA and dirB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's lay down some assumptions:

- Your shell is `bash`
- Your *Directory A* is `dirA`
- Your *Directory B* is `dirB`
- Your *Directory C* does not exist yet, but will be named `dirC`
- All the files you care about exist in `dirA` or `dirB` or are possibly duplicated in those directories

The simplest way I can think of is to:

```
rm -rf dirC; mkdir dirC
cp -p dirB/*.dm4 dirC/
cp -p dirA/*.dm4 dirC/
diff <(ls dirA) <(ls dirB)
```

That will put all .dm4 files into `dirC` and produce a `diff` listing of the two directories.

If you need a higher level of detail than that, please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/521813/edit) to be more specific.

**UPDATE:**

Suppose you have these files:

```
$ ls -1 dir{A,B}/*
dirA/apple.dm4
dirA/banana.dm4
dirA/date.dm4
dirA/fig.dm4
dirB/apple.dm4
dirB/elderberry.dm4
dirB/fig.dm4
dirB/grape.dm4
dirB/huckleberry.dm4
```

Notice that some files are duplicated, some are only in `dirA`, some are only in `dirB`.  Neither directory has a `cherry.dm4` file, for what it's worth.

And also suppose you have a script foo.sh:

```
$ cat << EOF > foo.sh; chmod 755 foo.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
rm -rf dirC; mkdir dirC
cp -p dirB/*.dm4 dirC/
cp -p dirA/*.dm4 dirC/
diff <(ls dirA) <(ls dirB)
EOF
```

Running `foo.sh` produces:

```
$ ./foo.sh
2,3c2
< banana.dm4
< date.dm4
---
> elderberry.dm4
4a4,5
> grape.dm4
> huckleberry.dm4
$ ls -1 dirC/*
dirC/apple.dm4
dirC/banana.dm4
dirC/date.dm4
dirC/elderberry.dm4
dirC/fig.dm4
dirC/grape.dm4
dirC/huckleberry.dm4
```

The `diff` output tells you that the .dm4 files missing from `dirA` are `elderberry`, `grape`, and `huckleberry`.  All of the files found in `dirA` **or** `dirB` are present in `dirC`.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. However, can you tell me what your first command - rm -rf dir; mkdir dirC is doing? From my understanding you are creating directory C, but I am not sure why you are using rm-rf dir C. Isn't that command used to delete a directory. Sorry I am new to linux so getting confused with rm.

Comment: It's there in case you need to run the script twice for whatever reason.  It ensures that `dirC` will always be present and empty when the script starts.

Comment: So as I follow your commands which you shared with me, am I fine in saying that            cp -p dirB/*.dm4 dirC/ - Will copy all .dm4 to dirC
cp -p dirA/*.dm4 dirC/ - Will copy all .dm4 to dirC
diff <(ls dirA) <(ls dirB) - Will find diff between both and B.                                        But my actuall intention is to find the difference first and then save all the different .dm4 to directory c. My reference folder is dir a. So if I want to see what .dm4s don't exist there which exist in dirB and then save all those to dirC, how should I go about it?

Comment: If you want to find the difference between the two directories first, then put the `diff` line first in the script.  Otherwise, your post is somewhat unclear.  Please see the last paragraph of my answer.  I suspect that if you clarify your question enough, it may become a duplicate of a question already asked on StackExchange.

Comment: Hello Jim, I have updated my question. You have still answered it pretty well however, may be now with better verbiage you might be able to totally understand wha I really want to achieve and might help me with it better. Thanks

Comment: I think this solution still works, then: copy all of B into C; copy all of A into C; Now all files that were in either A or B are also in C.  The `diff` output above will tell you which files are either only in A, only in B, or in both A and B.  I can't think of a simpler way to do it than that.  I will update my answer to show a proof of concept.

Comment: Hello Jim, thanks for the response. I have never created scripts but have just used standard commands as I am still new to unix. You think I can just run those commands one by one separately also instead of putting as script file like you mentioned? Will it work that way too.

Comment: Jim I had a basic question. So if I am currently on client's server. Now If I want to do all of the above and make sure the output file gets saved on my local machine without touch clients folder at all, can this be done. So basically the directory C, can that be created on my local machine with the results and not on clients machine even though I am currently logged in there and doing my analysis there.

Comment: As to running the commands by hand, absolutely!  That's really all that scripts do, is they store a long sequence of (possibly complex) commands so that you don't have to type them in.  It makes things less error-prone, and makes it easier to perform moderate- to high-complexity actions in a repeatable and reliable fashion.

Comment: Also can you get me the answer to my other query that can the dirC,where all my results will be copied, can it be created on my local machine, even though currently on on client's server where the actual folders which I am analyzing reside.

Comment: As to your client's server, I would create a test area on your own machine and experiment there.  There's nothing special about the files you create under `dirA` and `dirB`.  You can create dummy test data on your own machine, and so long as the files are named (something).dm4, the script will work.  Also, the script does not alter files in dirA or dirB, so you could make those directories and files read-only for safety, if you want.

Comment: Appreciate it Jim. Thank You for the help. I might bug you with more questions down the line, but this helps for now.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all files of dirA to dirC

```
cp dirA/*.dm4 dirC
```

Then copy all files from dirB, skipping exising files in dirC

```
cp -n dirB/*.dm4 dirC/
```

Man Page for `cp`:

> ```
>   -n, --no-clobber
>          do not overwrite an existing file (overrides a previous -i
>           option)
> ```

Note: `-n` checks for file names only, to check for versions, the`-u`pdate option might be interesting.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by skipping existing files in dirC? You mean to see when I use "cp -n dirB/*.dm4 dirC/" command, then all my .dm4 files will be copied to directory C and will overwrite the same name files which came from directory A or will it not overwrite those files and create a 2nd copy incase it already existed in A?